# Can I set logical operators to variables in php

Tags: php, operators, logic

I want to do something like (below), possible?

```
$operator = >=;
if($value.$operator 400){

// ...

}
```

Comment: No, and if you need to you might want to reconsider what you're doing.

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? You have only presented us with your attempt to solving your problem, which we know nothing about.

Comment: take the source code of the interpreter and add that functionality, compile, install and use that. otherwise, nope

Comment: Technically, it *is* possible using `eval` but would definitely not be recommended: http://ideone.com/J4Swn

Comment: I agree with @phant0m, you should post what you intended to do, perhaps there's a better way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't store operators as variables, but you *can* store functions (in PHP 5.3+).  Try that:

```
$operator = function($a){
    return $a >= 400;
}

if($operator($value)){
}
```

Or, I guess you could use a "normal" function:

```
function operator($a){
    return $a >= 400;
}

if(operator($value)){
}
```

Comment: One might consider giving the variable a better name too, something like `$isValid`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: If you want.  I just hacked that up quickly. :-P

Comment: I understand - it was more of a comment to the OP :-)

Comment: @Mahn: I don't mean to belittle Rocket's answer, but what exactly is so clever about this?

Comment: Well, I for one would not have thought of closures if all I needed were a single conditional statement, but as it turns out, it works for what OP is asking. I'm not saying it's an impressive work of engineering, just not something one would normally think of, simply because the idea seems too silly to consider.

Comment: @Mahn: That's why I also suggested "normal" functions :-P

Comment: @Mahn, ah, I see. Btw, you should use "@user" when you reply to someone  other than the person who wrote the answer, otherwise they don't get notified that you have replied. Rocket: Jonathon has a point you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can (**BUT SHOULD NEVER EVER DO**) is using `eval()`:

```
<?php
$value = 400;
$operator = '>=';
eval('if('.$value.$operator.' 400) echo "something";');
```

Again this is just to show you it can be done, but YOU SHOULD NEVER EVER USE `eval()` or I will personally kill a kitten!

And I seriously think you have a big flaw in your design if you think you need something like this.

As @rocket told in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620550/can-i-set-logical-operators-to-variables-in-php/11620609#comment15388125_11620609). A cleaner way of doing this is:

```
<?php
$value = 400;
$operator = '>=';
eval("\$result = $value$operator 400;");

if ($result) {
    echo 'Something';
}
```

And **no** this being cleaner doesn't mean you can use. I'm serious if you use this I'm going to hunt you down ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to give "+1" for "or I will personally kill a kitten, but why do you post it at all if you feel like that about the "solution"?

Comment: @phant0m OP asked whether it is possible and yes it is

Comment: If you gonna use `eval`, wouldn't it be better to do `eval("\$result = $value$operator 400;");  if($result){...}`?

Comment: @Rocket Yup that would more ---cleaner--- less dirty / filthy / hacky / plain old stupid. :)

Comment: Better yet: `$result = eval("return $value$operator 400;");` :-P

Comment: I would kill myself if I were working with someone elses code and saw this.

Comment: Hehe I don't think I'll be using eval like this any time soon. Had a good laugh none the less though.